# how to solve: ssh "Connection corrupted" error

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-linux

On a Oracle/RedHat VM that I use every days (probably after the nightly upgrades) I've this authentication error:

```
$ ssh machine
Bad packet length NNNNNNN. ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to A.B.C.D port NN: Connection corrupted
```

A more debugged view:

```
$ ssh -vvvv machine
...
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu3.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
...
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
...
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
...
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
Bad packet length VERY_LONG_NUMBER.
debug2: sshpkt_disconnect: sending SSH2_MSG_DISCONNECT: Packet corrupt
debug3: send packet: type 1
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to a.b.c.d port xyz: Connection corrupted
```

**ADD**
My client machine is Ubuntu

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu3.2, OpenSSL 3.0.10 1 Aug 2023
```

Comment: Where is the VM hosted (cloud or local)? Can you try specifying a different cipher (`-c` option)? There can be many causes and it's probably impossible to tell from afar, but my initial guesses would be either RAM issues or some "network filtering" appliance messing up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've encountered this problem as well.

I was able to work around it with `ssh -c aes256-gcm@openssh.com`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 9):

The [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1828512/489889) of [Mike Quin](https://superuser.com/users/1887235/mike-quin) totally saved my day.
I want add a bit of context to clarify.

A more explicit example of answer could be:

```
ssh -c aes256-gcm@openssh.com user@host.example.com
```

where `-c` is the `cipher_spec`, from the SSH manual (`man ssh`):

```
-c cipher_spec
 Selects the cipher specification for encrypting the
 session.  cipher_spec is a comma‐separated list of 
 ciphers listed in order of preference.  See the Ciphers 
 key‐word in ssh_config(5) for more information.
```

and following the suggestion, in the SSH_config manual (`man 5 ssh_config`):

```
       Ciphers
               Specifies  the  ciphers allowed and their order of
               preference.  Multiple ciphers must be  comma‐separated. 
               If  the  specified list begins with a ‘+’
               character, then the specified ciphers will be  
               appended  to  the  default  set instead of replacing
               them.  If the specified list  begins  with  a  ‘‐’
               character,  then  the specified ciphers (including
               wildcards) will be removed from  the  default  set
               instead  of replacing them.  If the specified list
               begins with a ‘^’ character,  then  the  specified
               ciphers  will be placed at the head of the default
               set.

               The supported ciphers are:

                     3des‐cbc
                     aes128‐cbc
                     aes192‐cbc
                     aes256‐cbc
                     aes128‐ctr
                     aes192‐ctr
                     aes256‐ctr
                     aes128‐gcm@openssh.com
                     aes256‐gcm@openssh.com
                     chacha20‐poly1305@openssh.com

               The default is:

                     chacha20‐poly1305@openssh.com,
                     aes128‐ctr,aes192‐ctr,aes256‐ctr,
                     aes128‐gcm@openssh.com,aes256‐gcm@openssh.com

               The list of available ciphers may also be obtained
               using "ssh ‐Q cipher".
```

And used in the config could be:

```
Host host.example.com
        Port 22
        User user
        Ciphers aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

Answer (score 5):

For those looking for an actual explanation and server side fix:

It looks like [Oracle released](https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2023-48795.html) fixes for the [Terrapin Attack](https://terrapin-attack.com/) in their openssh-server package on February 1st, 2024. Updated package version is `openssh-server-8.0p1-19.el8_9.2.x86_64`.

Downgrading openssh-server to version `8.0p1-19.el8_8` will revert the update and SSH will work again, although this probably not advisable.

I think the most advisable solution is disable the `CHACHA20-POLY1305` cipher as written in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/765347/how-do-you-mitigate-the-terrapin-ssh-attack) post.

As I still could not SSH into our OL servers due to following (other) error:

```
Corrupted MAC on input.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to A.B.C.D port 22: message authentication code incorrect
```

I've also disabled the `AES-*-CTR` ciphers, e.g.

```
# cat /etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/TERRAPIN.pmod
cipher@ssh = -CHACHA20* -AES-*-CTR
ssh_etm = 0
```

```
# update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:TERRAPIN
# systemctl restart sshd
```

This results in automatic cipher detection to `aes128-gcm` which should be sufficient secure

```
$ ssh -v <client>
...
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-gcm@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
```

**Update Feb 16th, 2024**: [Oracle released a fix for this issue](https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2024-12164.html), package `openssh-server-8.0p1-19.0.1.el8_9.2.x86_64`

The workaround can be reverted as follows:

```
# rm /etc/crypto-policies/policies/modules/TERRAPIN.pmod
# update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT
# systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the workaround. On Feb 7th though it seems that Oracle has removed the upgrade. Only libssh is in the upgrade list now.